# extjs 4 rendering tooltip on grid on tabpanel

Tags: grid, extjs4, tabpanel, renderer

i am working with Extjs 4 & using Designer 1.2.0 
i am facing problems with grid's **renderer** function that i am using to display tooltip. The grid is placed in tab panel. Everything works fine for first time when i open tab panel,but when i close tab panel & reopen it , the initComponent() does not get called again & so **tooltip** does not show up & **hyperlink** effect goes off. What can be solution for this problem?
below is my code :

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ItemManager', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.ItemManager',

    initComponent: function() {
       Ext.QuickTips.init();
         var me = this;
         me.callParent(arguments);
              me.down('#itemManager').columns[3].renderer=function(value,metaData,record,colIndex,store,view){
                var imgpath="<img style=\'margin: 2px 0;height:150px;width:150px;\' src=\' /items/"+record.data.id +" '/>";

                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=" '+imgpath +'"' ;
                return '<a href="/items/imgdownload?id='+record.data.id+'">'+ record.data.img_filename +'</a>';
              }
      }
});
```

However when i write renderer code in **ui**  file generated by exporting project from designer then everything works fine. The problem is if i write renderer in **ui** file, it will get **overwritten** everytime i export the project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Ext.QuickTips.init()` should only be called 1 time and needs to be relocated to a global location.
2. You need to relocate your rendered definition to the actual column it belongs to: `{ ..., dataIndex : 'myColumn', rendered : function (value, metaData, etc) { return value; }, title : 'My Column Title', ... }`

**EDIT**

**Below is an example:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ItemManager', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.ItemManager',

    initComponent: function() {
        //Ext.QuickTips.init(); // move to global js file. only call once.
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        if (!me.down('#itemManager').columns[3].renderer) {
            me.down('#itemManager').columns[3].renderer=function(value,metaData,record,colIndex,store,view) {
                var imgpath="<img style=\'margin: 2px 0;height:150px;width:150px;\' src=\' /items/"+record.data.id +" '/>";

                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=" '+imgpath +'"' ;
                return '<a href="/items/imgdownload?id='+record.data.id+'">'+ record.data.img_filename +'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if u luk @ques thoroughly u will notice that i have said im using ext desginer 1.2 that does not have renderer option to specify...so if i inclu code in js that is created after exporting it as u said, next time when i export xds the code(renderer) written by me overwritten..so i can not include renderer in column confg

Comment: Please review and apply the example I added. Also, please do not forget to move your `Ext.QuickTips.init();` to a global location as it should only be called once.